# How to avoid cache slams in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, memcached

how do I avoid cache slams  (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/caching.html#cache-slams) ? this question is not about doctrine but cache in general

I need something like this

```
//pseudo code
// $cacheKey = 'randomCacheKey'.
if(Cache::has($cacheKey)) {
 return Cache::get($cacheKey);
}
//do some work
$valueToCache = $this->someComplexTask();
Cache::set($cacheKey, $valueToCache);
return $valueToCache;
```

the question is, how do I need to do it, to avoid cache slams?
For example if I have 200 parallel requests, and all of them will notice that there is no cache, they all will try to write to same, key, with will lead to spike in cpu/memory/db queries and etc.
so I need only one of them to write to this cache, and all others should wait for it. How do I do it?

this one is probably has something to do with atomic locks but it's not clear to me how do I use it, doc's for it doesn't me (it's too much "hello world"-like example).

Comment: You could warm up the cache in advance or you could leverage a locking mechanism to make sure only 1 request will write cache

Comment: @PtrTon yeah, I would like to use locking, but I can't figure out how. I'm afraid that I can hit myself in the face

Comment: You can do some locking with semaphores https://www.exakat.io/prevent-multiple-php-scripts-at-the-same-time/

Comment: when it comes to locking I prefer to use the [symfony lock component[(https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html). It supports 6 different stores for locking and has been documented well.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe solution is to never call Cache from a user request context. A cron-job which hits a local URL to refresh cache data is perfectly safe from such race conditions and memory churn associated.

http://notmysock.org/blog/php/user-cache-timebomb.html

Comment: Yeah, I&#39;ve read that post, but I need it to be fresh, can&#39;t go with once in a minute. I need it once on 5-10 seconds

Comment: Have a queued job that runs and re-queues itself with a 5-10 second delay?

Comment: @Dwight yeah, might be a thing